# CSS Filters to create a solid border around an object

Tags: html, css, filter

### Description of Problem ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkeqA/3/)):

I'm attempting to make a solid border around a PNG with transparency, so `box-shadow` is not an option (as it would simply shadow the square corners of the image).

How can I get a `filter: drop-shadow()` to create a border around the entire element without resorting to blurring or spreading the shadow? Can I apply multiple filters to the same element to achieve this effect? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

### Code:

```
#object {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -211px;
    margin-top: -120px;
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px white);
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just using a border? I'm confused.

Comment: Just as a side-note: if the image itself is circular, obviously you could use `border-radius` property to get `box-shadow` to work.

Comment: @IanClark Because, as stated, it's a transparent PNG and borders wouldn't conform to the shape of the image. The Fiddle is purely exemplary of the issue.

Comment: The shape of the image? You mean because it's a circle? Why doesn't [this work](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/GkeqA/2/)

Comment: @HashemQolami The image itself is not circular, unfortunately. The Fiddle was just to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What is the shape of the image? Maybe if you actually showed us a proper example of what you're trying to do we might be able to help.

Comment: @IanClark The image is not circular. I will update the Fiddle since it is causing confusion.

Comment: Fiddle is updated. http://jsfiddle.net/GkeqA/3/

Comment: So you want to add a border the image by calculating what the transparent parts are and stroking them...

Comment: @IanClark That sounds accurate, yes. I apologize for the earlier confusion with the misleading Fiddle.

Comment: How many of these images are you going to have? are they dynamically generated (even if they are) - wouldn't it be easier to add the border to the image itself??

Comment: Surely the best way to achieve this would just be to amend the image, it doesn't look like this filter does the job and [only webkit supports filters](http://caniuse.com/css-filters)

Comment: The images cannot be altered; there are thousands of them and they are served statically from another source. I was hoping for some sort of obscure ability to layer filters on the object, but evidently it's not possible.

Comment: ok, this is far from beeing perfect, but you could duplicate the image, change it's color and place it to your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/GkeqA/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** [Oh look I did something!](http://jsfiddle.net/GkeqA/7/)... My answer still stands

So, it sounds like the question you're really asking is *"How can I add a stroke to a non-square image using CSS"*, and my answer would be - *you can't*. As you've found out, it looks like webkit is able to achieve some nice affects with `filter`, [but that won't work on Firefox or IE](http://caniuse.com/css-filters), so  I don't really see the point in exploring filters further (unless you're entire audience are using Webkit/Blink).

My suggestion would just be to edit the images yourself. Perhaps you could recruit a server-side library such as GD or ImageMagick (probably bad solutions, but that's all I know for PHP) to handle the automation.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussion. I'm still not sure this is the route I'll be taking but it's at least something I'll try out. And, side note, Firefox/Mozilla does support filters (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) in a limited way through SVGs (if you can call that supporting it). Similarly, you can even do it in IE, too (http://demosthenes.info/blog/600/Creating-a-True-Cross-Browser-Drop-Shadow-Effect-With-CSS3-amp-SVG). Both are completely wonky and perform very poorly compared to WebKit, though.

Comment: @daveycroqet NP :) - for now, I'd just look at use some server-side library to manipulate the images. You just use it to make the images white for example, and then `transform: scale()` the original as I did in my example.

Comment: @IanClark That would be great. The only downside of that is it causes server overload to serve images on the fly.

Comment: @HashemQolami - yeh I agree, though I'd suggest caching them so you don't do it all the time. Either that or use some other program to batch the 1000 images in one go :)

Comment: Pretty nasty answer. IE is dead. Maybe they had a change if they did implement filter. No it sucked for more reasons. And yes filter: outline(2px white) should also be implemented.

Comment: @Joeri this answer was provided 9 years ago. It is naturally outdated. If you can provide a better answer suitable for 2023, please do.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution I found:

```css
.myObject {
    filter: 
        drop-shadow( 1px  0px 0px black) 
        drop-shadow(-1px  0px 0px black)
        drop-shadow( 0px  1px 0px black) 
        drop-shadow( 0px -1px 0px black);
}
```

Filter can be chained, but they will also apply to the result of previous filters. That's why the solution from Erick does not work.

The scale technique of Ian/Hashem only works on convex images with no hole in them. And even though, unless your image is a circle, the thickness of the border won't be homogeneous.

Also, don't bother adding a vendor prefix. In 2023, all major browsers support the CSS filter property: https://caniuse.com/css-filters

Comment: Thank you! I tried a variant of this myself, but ended up with very jagged corners - turns out drop-shadowing along only one coordinate at once is the solution. This doesn't make perfect corners every time but comes a lot closer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Ian, but if you don't care about *non-Webkit* web browsers which [don't support](http://caniuse.com/css-filters) CSS filters, you could duplicate the image and use a combination of [`grayscale()`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#funcdef-grayscale) and [`brightness()`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#funcdef-brightness) functions to fake the effect.

For instance:

```
<div class="shadow">
    <img id="object" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZgGX.png" />
</div>
```

```css
div.shadow:before {
    content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZgGX.png);

    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -211px;
    margin-top: -120px;

    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(100);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/GkeqA/6/)**.

Comment: I find the use of using `:before` and `content` a little funny. If you're serving dynamic data (as it seems @daveycroqet is) then how would you achieve this dynamically for a range of images given that you can't inline-style a `:before`. I think *if* you really wanted to do this, you'd be better off duplicating the content in a similar way to how I did, just because it would be easier to style.

Comment: @IanClark `then how would you achieve this dynamically` I can't :) There's no way to achieve that. I think I've missed something. I'll respectfully delete my answer then :)

Comment: You both have ingenious ways of dealing with the problem. Don't delete it, just in case it serves someone else's purposes!

Comment: Oh you've got points now, would be a shame! In fact it's Friday, we both attempted to answer this odd request, I'm upvoting you!

Answer (score 2):

Since then, Microsoft announced that IE 11 will no longer be supported starting 2021.

So, if you want to keep using the filters, you can always use it multiple times.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ErickXavier/cw46Lso5/

```
.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px white) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px white) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px white) drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px white);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it!!
Please check the Codepen.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzYGML

```
<filter id="border2" >
  <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha" radius="2" />
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1"/>
    <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0"/>
    <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="over" />
</filter>
```

Comment: Works great but I had to use different function values to get it to work. 

`<feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0 0 0"/>`